# How make subcategories like divide between products in woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How make subcategories like divide between products in woocommerce. It's must be looks like this:

Category 1 
- Subcategory 1 
-- Product 
-- Product 
-- Product 
- Subcategory 2 
-- Product 
-- Product 
-- Product

Comment: Hi, can you tell me , how you have added this list. Did you use category widget?And if possible then please share the url of that page.

Comment: @SouvikSikdar, I find a few ways here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561460/get-woocommerce-subcategory-products
But i get only subpages with products in category page. If follow link to subcategory page, there will be empty...although there must be products